# Why are 2/3 height bricks with studs on the side 2 studs deep?

Tags: piece-information, piece-usage

This question is regarding the 2/3 height bricks with studs on the side. The two that I am aware of are 99206 and 87609:

[image: 99206] [image: 87609]

If you haven't seen them before, these are functionally somewhat similar to an Erling brick used on its side. I'm curious why these bricks seem to be larger than they need to be. It seems to me that these could fit in more places and be more useful if they were 1x2 and 1x4 respectively. Something like a 1 plate shorter version of 11211 and 30414:

[image: 11211] [image: 30414]

Does the extra plate surrounding these parts create new ways that they can be used? Was mold design a factor in creating these parts the way they are?

Comment: Mold design is most certainly not the reason as I can't imagine these molds being less complex

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the case of 87609, the piece was first used in 2010 as part of the grill/bumper assembly for vehicles that were the standard 6 studs wide. Its length would appear to be a result of its original purpose. Its width also allows for attaching two rows of detail:

[image]

---

99206 showed up first in 2012. Its design allows for a more compact construction in situations like this:

[image]

If the piece were only 1x2, it would have to attach to another part above or below it. The extension lets you attach it flush from behind.

Comment: Well put. I kept mulling it over but couldn't put my finger on it....

Comment: The smaller pieces you describe would indeed be useful, too.